# Any helper methods for walking through the model tree?

Tags: helper, autodesk-viewer

I have a requirement to traverse the model tree and at each node perform some business logic, I was wondering if there are any helper methods that I could use that will help with moving through the nodes. Such as breadth first search or depth first search or even simple methods for getting a nodes children and parents?

Also methods for finding leaf nodes would be very helpful.

(Also if possible it would be great if these where provided in javascript rather than ES6, I know Phillipe Leefsma has a blog article that has a piece of code for finding leaf nodes but it is in ES6 and I can't seem to get it converted back to Javascript)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of getting all the children given an instance tree and a node is
`instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(node, callback)` where all the children dbids are in the callback.

To traverse through the tree, first get the instancee tree and the root id:

```
var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
var rootId = this.rootId = instanceTree.getRootId();
```

Then the best way is using breadth-first search:

```
function getAlldbIds (rootId) {
    var alldbId = [];
    if (!rootId) {
        return alldbId;
    }
    var queue = [];
    queue.push(rootId);
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        var node = queue.shift();
        alldbId.push(node);
        instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(node, function(childrenIds) {
            queue.push(childrenIds);
        });
    }
    return alldbId;
}
```

You can modify your method to optimize for performance.

Read more about it here: https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/12/select-all-elements-in-the-viewer-with-view-and-data-api-with-javascript.html